# Recurrence of Markov chain

Tags: recurrence-relations, markov-chains

I am trying Example 13.6 [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Egravner/MAT135B/materials/ch13.pdf). The solution is given there itself. But when I am trying to solve it by definition of the recurrent state, I am not getting the answer. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? 
Recurrent state: Suppose $f_{ii}$ be the probability that starting from state $i$, the chain eventually comes back to $i$, then if $i$ is recurrent, then $f_{ii}=1$. 
In this example, I am trying to prove that state 6 is recurrent using the above definition. So far, I have done this:
Let $f_{ii}=f_{ii}^1+f_{ii}^2+...$, where $f_{ii}^n$ is the probability that the chain comes back to state $i$ starting from $i$ for the first time in $n$ steps.

$$ f_{66}^1=0.7, \, \text{and } f_{66}^2+f_{66}^3+...=(0.3)\frac{1}{(1-0.3)}\frac{1}{(1-0.35)}(0.35). $$
Here $f_{66}^1$ is the probability that the chain comes back to 6 in one step. $f_{66}^2=0$, $f_{66}^3=(0.3)(0.7)(0.5)$.

Thus, in the expression $f_{66}^2+f_{66}^3+...=(0.3)\frac{1}{(1-0.3)}\frac{1}{(1-0.35)}(0.35)$, $0.3$ is the probability of going from state 6 to 4.

$\frac{1}{(1-0.3)}=1+0.3+0.3^2+...$ is the probability of taking loops in state 4, where $0.3^n$ denotes that $n$ loops are taken, similarly,

$\frac{1}{(1-0.35)}$ is the probability of taking loops between states 4 and 5.

The last term $0.35$ is the probability of moving from state 4 to 5, and then from 5 to 6.

If I sum the above terms, I am getting $0.9307$ instead of $1$. Why is this so? I am unable to figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Didn't fully understand your solution, but is it not easier to calculate the probability of never returning to state 6 again, so being trapped forever between 4 and 5?

Comment: @PedroSilva I agree, we can make use of the results available to prove this, however, I wanted to see if I do it manually, am I doing it right. As for the solution, I tried taking different cases, like, it moves from 6 to 4 to 5, or 6 to 4, then a loop, then 5, and so on, and write its probability accordingly.